# How to remove comment feed from Disqus comment plugin?

Tags: disqus

Can I remove the comment feed which is displayed under the comments from Disqus commenting platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The option is available in your Disqus settings, the URL is
`http://siteID.disqus.com/admin/settings/` (replace **siteID** with yours site's profile id).

Now switch to the Discovery tab and choose a Discovery Level for your Disqus comments. If you don't want any comment feed under your comments, then choose "Just comments" from the options. 
[image: screen shot]

Save changes and done. Now the comments feed has been removed.